# Dynamic SQL pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm using the following SQL (with SQL Server 2016) to pivot a list of test results from our LMS (Moodle):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         u.firstname AS name,
         u.lastname AS last_name,
         u.idnumber AS id_number,
         gi.itemname AS exam_name,
         CAST(gg.finalgrade / gi.grademax * 100 AS integer) AS grade
     FROM  
         mdl_grade_grades gg 
     INNER JOIN 
         mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id 
     INNER JOIN 
         mdl_course c ON gi.courseid = c.id 
     INNER JOIN 
         mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
     WHERE 
         (gi.itemname IS NOT NULL) 
         AND (gi.courseid = 123)) SOURCE
PIVOT 
    (MAX(grade)
     FOR exam_name IN ([Exam ABC], [Exam DEF], [Exam GHI],
                       [Exam JKL], [Exam XYZ])
    ) PIVT
ORDER BY 
    id_number
```

The result will be:

```
name    last name   id number   division    region      branch      Exam ABC    Exam DEF    Exam GHI    Exam JKL    Exam XYZ
John    Tester      3343664     ABC         WEST RGN    A AGY       65                                  44
Kenny   Quipton     4342423     DDA         CENTRAL     RGN FRN     88          66          90                      89
Molefi  Manase      5456545     CCS         ABC RGN     XXX SOL     74          90          85          80          77
```

My only issue with this is that the exam names have to be hardcoded in the `FOR IN(...)` list, so each time something changes the list has to be manually updated.

Can this SQL be rewritten using dynamic SQL?

What is better - using `Stuff()` or `FOR XML PATH`, or something else?

I can't use stored procedures (the application does not support them).

Comment: Post sample data please, from all tables used

Answer (score 0):

No need of stored procedures and FOR XML Path for comma concatination.
Just put the below code into your query builder and send it to Database server.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)='', @COL_NAMES VARCHAR(MAX)='';


--PREPARING EXAM NAMES LIST
SELECT @COL_NAMES = @COL_NAMES+ itemname+',' FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT  gi.itemname 
FROM mdl_grade_grades gg 
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_course c ON gi.courseid = c.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_course_categories cc ON c.category = cc.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
WHERE (gi.itemname IS NOT NULL) 
AND (gi.courseid = 123)
);

SELECT @COL_NAMES = LEFT(@COL_NAMES,LEN(@COL_NAMES)-1 );



--PREPARING DYNAMIC QUERY
SELECT @SQL = 
'SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        u.firstname AS name,
        u.lastname AS last_name,
        u.idnumber AS id_number,
        gi.itemname AS exam_name,
        CAST(gg.finalgrade / gi.grademax * 100 AS integer) AS grade
    FROM mdl_grade_grades gg 
    INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id 
    INNER JOIN mdl_course c ON gi.courseid = c.id 
    INNER JOIN mdl_course_categories cc ON c.category = cc.id 
    INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
    WHERE (gi.itemname IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (gi.courseid = 123)
) SOURCE
PIVOT (
    MAX(grade)
    FOR exam_name IN ('+@COL_NAMES+'
    )
) PIVT
ORDER BY id_number'


EXEC (@SQL);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in Management Studio: 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14 Incorrect syntax near ';'

Answer (score 0):

this uses `for xml` but should work the same either way

```
DECLARE @exams nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max)
SET     @exams = SELECT STUFF(SELECT ',',  + QUOTENAME(t.itemname)
                         FROM (
                           SELECT DISTINCT gi.itemname 
                           FROM   mdl_grade_items gi 
                           WHERE  gi.itemname IS NOT NULL AND gi.courseid = 123
                           ORDER BY gi.itemname 
                         ) t
              FOR XML PATH(''), 0, 1, '')

SET    @sql = N'
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
       (SELECT
           u.firstname AS name,
           u.lastname AS last_name,
           u.idnumber AS id_number,
           gi.itemname AS exam_name,
           CAST(gg.finalgrade / gi.grademax * 100 AS integer) AS grade
        FROM  
           mdl_grade_grades gg 
        INNER JOIN 
           mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id 
        INNER JOIN 
           mdl_course c ON gi.courseid = c.id 
        INNER JOIN 
           mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
        WHERE 
           (gi.itemname IS NOT NULL) 
           AND (gi.courseid = 123)) SOURCE
    PIVOT 
       (MAX(grade)
         FOR exam_name IN (' + @exams + ')
       ) PIVT
    ORDER BY 
       id_number 
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```